# MS-Access 2007: Error while trying to open a form: "There isn't enough free memory to update the display. Close unneeded programs and try again."

Tags: ms-access-2007

I was trying to create an area map to display information programmatically... I added several rectangles to it (around 500) and when I tried to turn it to the form view from design view (without adding any code), it displayed the memory error... I closed the form and then the application and restarted my machine, but since then even though the rest of the application is running fine but the form I designed is not even opening (in either of the views), and displays the above-mentioned error each time... I have spent considerable time designing this form and would very much like it to work... I am no access expert and have just some workable knowledge... will appreciate any pointers to a solution.. thanks

Comment: 500 rectangles  -- I don't think Access is designed for that. You might have more luck with a current 64bit version of Office, but this would be a rather expensive solution...

Comment: tried to open in office 365, 64-bit version.. but got a different error this time.. seems that the form has got corrupted.. tried to recover it using different methods.. none worked.. and recreating it using 500 boxes, of different sizes, arranged in a different fashion, to test it on 64-bit version will need a different sort of patience from my side.. so maybe some other day... thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Ouch. Just for testing, you can use [CreateControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.createcontrol) in a loop to create 500 rectangles. -- But if you want to use Access, and the map is for display only, I would use a report with its [.Line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.report.line) method (assuming the rectangles are based on existing data).

Comment: Actually, these boxes are to imitate the map of an area and hence are to be arranged in a specific order and the sizes differ too... they all will have a specific name to imitate actual plot numbers and programmatically there color and features would have been edited to help with the planning for the area... the file I created with the 32 bit version got corrupted when it reached around that many boxes.. so will have to recreate the map manually again after getting the 64 bit version installed to see if it works there...

Comment: or may be I will have to try to see beyond ms-access.. may be, python... will revert to this post if I am able to get around it somehow :)